# Solving and making sure

Tags: calculus, physics

1. There is a particle in a system.The mass of this particle is M=0.5 kg. The initial and final velocity are V0=2i , Vf=2j (i,j denote the unit vector in x, y axes)

Question: 1) The initial and final momentum; 2) The impulse exerts on this particle

I know that: p=mv  so
v=(2+2)/2 = 2
Then p= 0.5×2 = 1 now how to get initial and final momentum

Another way: P initial = Mass × V initial = 1 ,
P final = Mass × V final = 1
Is this way true?

And I couldn't get the impulse!

Comment: $\vec p_i=m\vec v_i=m(2,0); \vec p_f = m\vec v_f=m(0,2);\delta \vec p =m(0,2)-m(2,0)=m(-2,2).$

Comment: But we have the magnitude of the mass, should I multiply in velocity?!! If I do that , each of initial and final momentum will equal to 1 , right?

Comment: user671061. m is a scalar(a number), $\vec v$ is a vector; $\vec p_i  =m \vec v_i =(2m,0)=(1,0)$; $\vec p_f=(0,2m)=(0,1)$; and finally $\Delta \vec p= (-2m,2m)=(-1,1)$.All 3 are vectors are different , their x and y components are different. Is this OK?

Comment: Yes I got it, thanks a lot and sorry for disturbing you

Comment: No disturbance whatever. You are welcome:)